# Há crase em "voltava a casa"?

Tags: crase, artigos-definidos

Estávamos ouvindo uma canção que dizia "Já era bem tarde e voltávamos a casa quando vimos..." e então fui perguntado: esse "a casa" leva o acento grave?  Ou melhor, há a ocorrência de crase?

Comment: Tendo eu postado uma resposta à minha própria pergunta (e é claro que eu a considero correta), aceitarei aquela que tiver mais votos. Nem sei se o sistema permite que o autor da pergunta aceite sua própria resposta mas, supondo que seja possível, não seria ético que eu aceitasse a minha sem uma base nos votos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na frase que dás, não. No sentido *regressar à casa onde se vive*, o artigo não é usado. Caso contrário, aplicam-se as regras gerais para uso do artigo (e, estando nós a usar o artigo definido, terá de ser uma casa específica e que a outra parte consiga recuperar).

> Vou voltar a casa. (à minha casa; à casa onde vivo)
>   Vou voltar à casa. (a uma casa em específico, que pode ser identificada pelo contexto)

Um caso mais difícil é quando falamos em ir a casa de outra pessoa. Nesse caso, pode ser possível usar as duas formas.

> — Vais a/à casa da Maria? — Não, vou a casa/à casa do João.
>   — Vais a/à casa da Maria? — Não, vou à do João.

Mas repara que, na resposta, estando *casa* omitido, **à** é já obrigatório. Exemplos do CETEMPúblico:

> - Os habitantes do prédio foram **para casa de familiares**.
> - Assim, domingo à noite, Michéle Thévenot saiu livre de um carro, chamou um táxi, e foi **para casa de uma amiga**, de onde telefonou à Embaixada de França.
> - Raimundo passou o fim-de-semana numa casa que tem em Coimbra -- e na volta passou por sua casa na Guarda para trazer roupa e um computador -- e Luís Brígida foi **para casa de um irmão** no Seixal.
> - Do restaurante, pegámos em Lonnie e no seu «diddley-bow» e fomos **a casa de Big Jack Johnson**.
> - «Faço praia de vez em quando na [Figueira da] Foz, mas, fora disso, fico em casa ou vou **a casa de uns amigos**» .

O último exemplo é esclarecedor. Com *à casa de uns amigos* estaríamos a referir-nos a uma casa em específico (cujos donos ou arrendatários fossem uns amigos). Mas a interpretação mais saliente da última frase é a de que visita as casas dos vários amigos.

Havendo outros modificadores para *casa*, o artigo será também obrigatório:

> Vamos voltar à casa azul.
>   Não gostei desta casa, vamos voltar à [casa] que vimos antes e decidir se a compramos.

Comment: Se ao invés de usarmos a preposição "a", usarmos "até" ou "para" no modelo de frase "Vais a/à casa de Maria?", em pt-BR veremos que o artigo está sempre presente -  "Vais **para a** casa de Maria?", "Vais **até a** casa de Maria?", mas não seria idiomático dizer "Vais até casa de Maria?". Por outro lado, tirando a prova dos nove e substituindo "casa" por um substantivo masculino, veremos que o artigo é necessário.  "Tu vais ao domicílio de Maria?  Quem vai, vai a algum lugar.  Portanto não vejo como o artigo ou a preposição poderiam ser omitidos nesse caso em particular. Pelo menos em pt-BR.

Comment: 1) em Portugal é legítimo dizer _vou para/até casa da Maria_. Mas pode ser que ser que seja uma particularidade da variedade europeia 2) substituir _domicílio_ por _casa_ não é um teste válido. É como dizer se que um teste para saber se _returning home_ leva artigo antes de _home_ poderia ser substituir _home_ por _house_. A expressão é _voltar a casa_, não _voltar a [outro nome]_.

Comment: Aos meus ouvidos, "vou até casa de Maria" soa como "vou até "Casa de Maria", o nome de um local, prédio, instituição religiosa, etc.

Comment: @Centaurus adicionei alguns exemplos. Já agora, com _passar_ pode-se ver uma diferença: _vais em frente, passas pela/*por casa da Maria e depois viras à esquerda_. _Passar por casa da Maria_ implicaria lá entrar.

Comment: Artefacto, "pela" = "per/por + a", conforme tu sabes.

Comment: Artefacto, sem querer ser chato, mas quem escreveu aqueles exemplos?  Tu sabes que existe gente bem letrada que tem dificuldade com a crase.  Eu acredito que faltou o acento grave em "a casa de Big Jack" e em "a casa de uns amigos" e não que se trate de casos em que não se usa o artigo.  Será que tu consegues exemplos (para esse uso específico) dados por um gramático ou por um site de língua portuguesa?

Comment: @Centaurus Os exemplos são do CETEMPúblico, do tempo em que os jornais tinham dinheiro para revisores. Além disso, em Portugal não há dificuldade no uso da crase, porque há diferença fonética entre _a_ e _à_ (quando muito, as pessoas não sabem para que lado é o acento).

Answer (score 1):

Minhas regras particulares para crases:

1. Sentido de "para": "Vou voltar a casa" = "Vou voltar para a casa". Então tem crase.
2. Trocar o gênero para o masculino: "Vou voltar a casa" = "Vou voltar ao casebre". Então tem crase.

Ou seja, a crase é a versão feminina do "ao". Então pra não escrever "voltar aa casa", usa-se o artigo com o acento grave.

"Vou voltar a casa" dá o sentido de que você vai trazer a casa de volta.

Answer (score -1):

Em pt-BR (e acredito que também no Português europeu) **a presença do artigo definido antes da palavra "casa" vai depender de se a casa é de quem fala ou não.** Quando alguém se refere à sua casa, o seu lar, não se usa o artigo. Consequentemente, não havendo artigo não poderá ocorrer crase.

- "Eu vou **para casa** agora. (minha casa) e amanhã eu vou **para a casa** de João."
- "Eu **voltava a casa** quando observei que..." (minha casa) Neste caso o "a" é apenas uma preposição.
- "Lucia está **em casa**." (em sua casa, apenas preposição)
- "Eu **fui à casa** de Tereza." (não é a minha casa, portanto "a + a")
- "Eu **voltei à casa** de Álvaro e encontrei..."  ("a + a = à", pois não se trata da minha casa. Obviamente, não haveria crase se a preposição usada não fosse "a". Por exemplo: "**voltava até/para a casa** de Álvaro".)
- "Lucia **está na casa** de sua mãe" ("em + a = na", pois não é sua casa) Neste último exemplo há quem não use o artigo e diga apenas "em casa de sua mãe".

Comment: Claro, crase é sempre com a+ a.

Comment: Centaurus, me lembro de poucas regras. Essa é uma delas. Só para você saber: decidi estudar "filologia portuguesa e brasileira" (ou seja língua e literatura) quando cheguei na universidade, porque nasci e fui criada no Brasil, mas nunca tinha estudado português formalmente. Queria que a ficha caísse. Eu sou intérprete, sabia? But I can't spell for [****].

Comment: @Lambie  É uma profissão que requer muita habilidade.  Não só conhecimento pleno das línguas em questão, mas também um bom ouvido, raciocínio rápido e muito bom senso quando se trata de um diálogo ao vivo que está caminhando para animosidade. Já tentei servir de interprete, por solicitação de terceiros, em uma palestra médica, e achei extremamente difícil acompanhar tudo o que o expositor dizia e traduzir ao mesmo tempo.  Mas, dizem que "practice makes perfect"..